# How do I programmatically add a new search page to the search page list?

Tags: 8, routes, search, plugins

I have been able to successfully create a search plugin for a custom module, which allows users to search for my custom entity by name. After creating this file, I have to enable it by visiting /admin/config/search/pages selecting my search type from the dropdown, and add it after specifying the target path. What is needed to do this within the module? I imagine I would have to create a route somewhere, and then associate this route with the search page list. Any advice on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've configured the plugin in UI, export the config and look for the configuration file `search.page.[search_plugin_id].yml`.

Remove the uuid and hash line and place the file in the directory `config/optional/` of the module.

You find examples in the core modules Node and User, see http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/user/config/optional/search.page.user_search.yml